# Problem involving three cyclic quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

I found out the following configuration in elementary geometry. I know it is true (by drawing in Geogebra) but I haven't proved it yet.

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle with the circumcircle $(O)$. $M$ is an arbitrary point on the edge $BC$. $AM$ intersects $(O)$ at $D$. The circumcircle of triangles $CMD$ and $BMD$ intersects the line $AC$ and $AB$ at $E$ and $F$. Then
>
> - $AEDF$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.
> - Let $H, I, G$ be the circumcenter of the circumcircle of three triangles $BMD$, $CMD$, $AEF$ correspondingly. Then five points $G, O, H, D, I$ are concyclic.

[image]

My question is: Is it a familiar configuration or result in elementary geometry? Are there any source to check new result in elementary geometry?

Please share with me more information about it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\measuredangle DEC=\measuredangle DMC=\measuredangle BFD,$$ which says that $AEDF$ is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you. I have proved this problem, but I don't know whether it was a well-known theorem or a special case of some other results.